# C# update - code reading/xml reader

Tags: c#

What would I add to this so that if there is no update available a message box pops up saying no update? Although this is probably an easy fix, I've been working on a lot of updating systems lately, but I'm just stumped on it.

```
        Version newVersion = null;
        string url = "";
        XmlTextReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            string xmlURL = "URL";
            reader = new XmlTextReader(xmlURL);
            reader.MoveToContent();
            string elementName = "";
            if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) &&
                (reader.Name == "App"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        elementName = reader.Name;
                    else
                    {
                        if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) &&
                            (reader.HasValue))
                        {
                            switch (elementName)
                            {
                                case "version":
                                    newVersion = new Version(reader.Value);
                                    break;
                                case "url":
                                    url = reader.Value;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reader != null) reader.Close();
        }
        Version curVersion = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version;
        if (curVersion.CompareTo(newVersion) < 0)
        {
            string title = "New Update Avaliable";
            string question = "Download Now?";
            if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBoxEx.Show(this, question, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
            {
                Process.Start(url);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can't you add an else branch when comparing versions, and show the message there?

Comment: But you do know how the `else` keyword works, right? If there's no update, it would fit in the else branch, or am I not getting this?

Comment: @Patrick Yes but the way I have the code set to read the version I can't do it that way, because then it reads the version incorrectly and always returns new update available.

Comment: Why and how does the code read the version incorrectly? What is the expected value and actual value in your algorithm?

Comment: @Patrick It reads incorrectly because I have have the update in a ".rar" file, and  put the version information coded into that rar file so if I use something else it reads incorrectly.

Comment: I bet the reason you're "stumped" is because you are not seeing any error message. You're not seeing any error message because your `catch {}` block is discarding it. Remove that block. Actually, remove `catch {}` from all the code you ever write.

Comment: You can use a `catch`-block if all it contains is a `throw;`. This can be useful if you're debugging with VisualStudio, and want to catch the exception exactly at the point it occurs.

Comment: @Dour High Arch Thank you for reply, but it is now worked out.

Comment: @Loadmaster Thank you for reply, but it is now worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something wrong with comparing `curVersion` to `newVersion`?

```
    if (curVersion == newVersion) {
        MessageBox.Show("No Update Needed");
    } else if (curVersion.CompareTo(newVersion) < 0)
    {
        string title = "New Update Avaliable";
        string question = "Download Now?";
        if (DialogResult.Yes == MessageBoxEx.Show(this, question, title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question))
        {
            Process.Start(url);
        }
    }
```